Usar diferente version de un mismo DLL en Visual studio 2022 c#
Visual studio 2022 c#
Necesito usar dos versiones de DLL pero que a nivel de funciones hacen lo mismo. He incluido los dos DLL con diferente nombre y les he cambiado el Alias (vamos a llamarlos A y B). Utilizando extern alias y using, he incluido las dos librerias. Esto lo estoy haciendo en una clase que luego quiero usar como objeto, y en función de la version seleccionada cuando creo el objeto, usar una libreria u otra.
El problema es que parece que tengo que crear todo por duplicado para definir con que versión voy a trabajar.
extern using libA;
extern using libB;
using VerA=libA.class;
using VerB=libB.class;

namespace test.resources
{
  internal class Tool
  {
    public VerX.Variable variable;
    public void method()
    {
      VerX.Method();
    }
  }
}

Y crear el objeto en el main
tool=new Tool();
tool.method();

Lo que me gustaría es de alguna manera, poder crear esa variable y metodo "VerX" con "VerA" o "VerB" cuando creo el objeto, en función de la version que escoja. Sin tener que crear  dos clases, una con la VerA y otra con la VerB, porque van a hacer lo mismo.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Y si tuvieran una interfaz y heredaran de ella podrias.. pero por lo que decis, a nivel funcional, son dos cosas distintas (aunque sean versiones de la misma) y las tenes que manejar como si fueran distintas...

La versión cuando y como la seleccionas??? Al inicio de la aplicación?? cada vez que creas un objeto??

Hola, la versión la quiero seleccionar cuando cree el objeto, de hecho es la parte que no se como hacer. Podria crear una clase diferente para cada una de las versiones, pero el contenido es exactamente le mismo, por tanto siempre tendria que estar copiando y pegando las modificaciones.
